# how to return null value when getter have null value instead return java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-rest

i query database and mapping it to class

```
MyDataClass myDataClass = myDataDao.findMyDataByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
```

and i map it to other class like this

```
MyOtherDataclass myOtherDataClass = new MyOtherDataClass();
myOtherDataClass.setBirthDate(myDataClass.getBirthDate().toString);
```

i know the `myDataClass.getBirthDate()` is null because `birthdate` value in my database is null.
if i insert value to `birthdate` in database, then its normal, everything works. but if it has no value, instead of throw `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`, i want to set it to null in json

i expect the result in json like this

```
{
AccountNumber: "12313",
BlaBla: "blabla",
BirthDate: null,
}
```

===========================================================================

**Found out the problem.**

i use `.toString()` on `myOtherDataClass.getBirthDate().toString()` so it throws null pointer.because birthDate in `myDataClass` is null. sorry that's my bad.

solved using

```
myOtherDataClass.setBirthDate(myDataClass.getBirthDate() != null ? myDataClass.getBirthDate().toString() : null);
```

Comment: what is throwing the null pointer? the getter? post your logs with stacktrace pls

Comment: Write a processor to handle null for each value.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf yes, i already edit the post. thx.

Comment: The real question here is why does `myOtherDataClass` store a date as a String? Don't do that. Use the original type as far as possible, and only convert it when you need to print or display it.

Comment: All this could have been pointed out in one second if you had posted the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any visibility to your classes (`myDataClass` and `myOtherDataClass`) so it is hard to say for sure why the getter is throwing the error. Still, and I am just guessing here, it might be that you are just looking for a quick one liner to deal with the null value, one answer to which would be:

`myOtherDataClass.setName((myDataClass.getName() != null) ? myDataClass.getName() : "somethingelse");`

This [ternary construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) could be used to render whatever you want for "somethingelse", including a null (I don't know how you are generating json, either, so I don't know precisely how you are processing a null.)

If you would like to see an entire example in action, here one is with a fake DAO with two instances (one named, and one not named).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

// The main method must be in a class named "Main".

class MyDataClass {
    String accountNumber;
    String blaBla;
    String name;
    
    public MyDataClass(String accountNumber, String blaBla) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.blaBla = blaBla;
    }
    
    public MyDataClass(String accountNumber, String blaBla, String name) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.blaBla = blaBla;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
}

class MyOtherDataClass {
    String name;
    String foo;

    public MyOtherDataClass() {
        this.foo = "bar";
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void printIt() {
      System.out.println("Name: "+ name );
      System.out.println("Foo: " + foo );
      System.out.println("\n");
   }
}


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDataClass myDataClassHasNoName = new MyDataClass("12345","BlaBla");
        MyDataClass myDataClassHasName = new MyDataClass("12346","BlaBla","Name");

        MyOtherDataClass myOtherDataClassHasName = new MyOtherDataClass();
        MyOtherDataClass myOtherDataClassHasNoName = new MyOtherDataClass();
        myOtherDataClassHasName.setName((myDataClassHasName.getName() != null) ? myDataClassHasName.getName() : "somethingelse");
        myOtherDataClassHasNoName.setName((myDataClassHasNoName.getName() != null) ? myDataClassHasNoName.getName() : "somethingelse");
        
        myOtherDataClassHasName.printIt();
        myOtherDataClassHasNoName.printIt();
        
    }
}
```

Here's a link [on mycompiler](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/AMAVORc)

Comment: thx for answer, but i have like 100 field to set. should i really put ternary operator in 100 field that i have to set?

Comment: nevermind the problem. i found out that i use ".toString() " on myDataClass.getBirthDate(). so it throws null pointer.because birthDate in database is null. sorry that's my foolishness.

thanks for answer. i use ternary operator to validate it, then do .toString().